# How to map class to existing view in database without primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a few views in my database which don't have primary keys; for example

```
dbo.Test { ForeignKeyId, Sum, Date }
```

Is there any way to map this for class with Entity Framework?

What I tried (and it didn't work):

1. Create normal model like a table (but it needs to upgrade database)
2. Ignore my class in model builder (but when I'm trying to access from context I got entity exception on invalid operation)

Comment: Any entity in Entity Framework **must have** a key - either a single column, or a tuple of multiple columns. If you can find one (or several) column(s) that form what could be a primary key, you need to **define** those columns as your primary key for that entity representing your view

Comment: But when i created it by another columns ( HasKey(x=>new (key,key2..) ) , i got message that i need to upgrade migrations. After that I need to put my tables into database that i don't want to do. Is there any ,,work around" for that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could map a view as a table. Something like this:

```
public class EntityTypeForViewMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityTypeForView>
{
    public EntityTypeForViewMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Name_Of_View"); // actual name of the view         
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to define a **primary key** for that entity